# Why did I calculate the wrong relative extrema for $y = –x^3 + 7x – 4$?

Tags: calculus

I am teaching myself the calculus component necessary to get through an econ based stats and applied math class.  The practice problem is to give the relative extrema and points of inflection of    $y =  –x^3 + 7x – 4.$ The application is for min and max prices / costs etc given an equation). I have first and second derivatives as:

$ y'(x) = -3x^2 + 7 $
$  y''(x) = -6x$

I then set $y'(x) = 0$ and solve

$-3x^2 + 7 = 0$ 
$-3x^2 = -7$
$x^2 = {-7\over-3} = \frac73$
$x = \sqrt{\frac73} ~= 1.53$

BUT the package tells me the answer is    $\dfrac1{\sqrt{21}}$.

##### My couple of questions

1. To find min and max values I solve first derivative for zero AND plug that into the original equation.  Is this the right approach?
2. Are my derivatives correct? I confirmed them using R (my coding skills much greater than my math skills):

   > D(expression(-x^3 + 7*x -4),"x")
   > 7 - 3 * x^2

   > D(D(expression(-x^3 + 7*x -4),"x"),"x")
   > -(3 * (2 * x))
3. Assuming the above, how does the $-3x^2 + 7 = 0$ get reduced to$\dfrac1{\sqrt{21}}$? It has been 23 years since I took algebra, and while it is not an excuse, it is a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is largely correct. We have $x^2=7/3$, so $x=\pm\sqrt{7/3}$. It may be that you rejected the negative root because for "physical" reasons the variable $x$ must be non-negative. Or it may be that you forgot about the possibility that $x=-\sqrt{7/3}$.

The number $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{21}}$ is **not** a solution of the equation $y'(x)=0$.
You can easily verify that the answer you got *is* a solution by substituting in $y'(x)$, and seeing whether the result is $0$. It is.

There are various alternate ways to write the solutions. For example, we can write the solutions as $\pm\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then you can multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{3}$ to obtain $\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{3}$. This procedure is called *rationalizing the denominator*. (Some people do not like square roots in the denominator.) Perhaps the person solving the problem made a mistake in rationalizing the denominator.

Yes, to find the **relative** (aka **local**) maximum and minimum values for your function, you substitute the two values where $y'(x)=0$. To *see* what's happening, using software or in some other way, graph the function. We hit the top of a hill at $x=\sqrt{7/3}$, and the bottom of a valley at $x=-\sqrt{7/3}$.

**Important:** Your function **does not** have a maximum or minimum. For very large positive $x$, it is huge negative, and for very large negative $x$, it is huge positive.

Comment: I missed the +/- in front of the sqrt.  Typo, thanks for catching that.  But you are agreeing with me that what the software tells me is correct 1/sqrt(21) is not actually right?  That would seem to underscore my inabilty to come up with that solution.

Comment: Certainly $1/\sqrt{21}$ is not a solution of $y'(x)=0$ for the function $y(x)$ that you wrote down. It is possible that you did not write down the correct $y(x)$.

Comment: no chance I copied it wrong, I used cut and paste.  I have been finding wrong answers all semested, in areas I have more confidence in I am better at alerting.  Since my algebra is poor, I thought i was being dumb.  THank you

Comment: Please see the important comment I added at the end. The function $y(x)$ has neither a maximum nor a minimum. But it does have **local** (relative) max and min.

Comment: It is a good observation, and noted